# Odd ColdFusion cfscript syntax issue

Tags: coldfusion

I'm having a very odd syntax error in my cfscript.

```
stFields = {
    "EligibilityQuery": { 
        "Patient": {
            "FirstName": arguments.data.lname, 
            "MiddleName": "", 
            "LastName": arguments.data.fname, 
            "DateOfBirth": dateformat(arguments.data.dob,'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
            "Gender": arguments.data.gender,
            "SSN": arguments.data.SSN,
            "Address": {
                "FirstLine": "", 
                "SecondLine": "",
                "ZipCode": arguments.data.ZipCode
            } 
        },
        "NPI": "1111111" 
    }
};

// call API
var authorization = "Basic: " & ToBase64('username:password');
cfhttp(method="POST", url="https://mysite/api/myAPI/", result="apiResult"){
    cfhttpparam(name="Authorization", type="header", value="#authorization#");
    cfhttpparam(name="Content-Type", type="header", value="application/json");
    cfhttpparam(type="body", value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#");
}
apiResult = deserializeJSON(apiResult.fileContent);
```

It's returning error on cfhttp (A script statement must end with ";".)

Error - The CFML compiler was processing:

```
cfhttp(method="POST", url="https://mysite/api/myAPI/", result="apiResult")
```

Where am I missing the ";"?

Comment: Isolate the problem by commenting out all code after the `strFields =` command.  Make sure you comment out each of the cfhttparam lines.  Run the code.  If no error occurs, take away the comments, one by one, and run the code until that particular error occurs.

Comment: @DanBracuk, I did it already. If I remove the whole cfhttp, it works. The error is there, but Idk why

Comment: So the code compiles with the `cfhttp` and without the `cfhttpparam` commands?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 - If that was a real username and password posted, you should change it **immediately** and be more careful in future. Especially as the code appears to deal with medical information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expects a `;` after `cfhttp(method="POST", url="https://mysite/api/myAPI/", result="apiResult")`.

Are you on CF9 or CF10? Try this:

```
// call API
var authorization = "Basic: " & ToBase64('username:password');

httpService = new http(method = "POST", charset = "utf-8", url = "https://mysite/api/myAPI/");

httpService.addParam(name = "Authorization", type = "header", value = "#authorization#");
httpService.addParam(name = "Content-Type", type = "header", value = "application/json");
httpService.addParam(type = "body", value = "#serializeJSON(stFields)#");

apiResult = httpService.send().getPrefix();
apiResult = deserializeJSON(apiResult.fileContent);
```